# SegNet results of train set (test via test_segmentation.py)

Tags: python-2.7, neural-network, caffe, conv-neural-network

I run SegNet on my own dataset (by [Segnet tutorial](http://mi.eng.cam.ac.uk/projects/segnet/tutorial.html#references)). I see great results via `test_segmentation.py`.
my problem is that I want to see the real net results and not test_segmentation own colorisation (via classes). 
for example, if I have trained net with 2 classes, so after the train I will see not only 2 colors (as we see with the classes), but we will see the real net color segmentation ([0.22,0.19,0.3....) lighter and darker as the net see it]
I hope that I explained myself well. thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it. the solution is to range `cmin` and `cmax` from 0 to 1 in the scipy saving method. for example: `scipy.misc.toimage(output, cmin=0.0, amax=1).save(/path/.../image.png)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a python script to achieve what you want. Take a look at [this script](https://github.com/malreddysid/caffe_scripts/blob/master/eval_SegNet.py).

The command `out = out['argmax']`, extracts the raw output, so you can get a segmentation map with 'lighter and darker' values as you wanted.

Comment: its not correct. you should see the image as it is. without take max/average/etc. argument. see my answer here.

Answer (score 0):

When you say the 'real' net color segmentation I will assume that you mean the probability maps. Effectively the last layer will have one map for every class; and if you check the function predict in inference.py, they take the argmax; that is the channel (which represents the class) with the highest probability. If you want to get these maps, you just have to get the data without computing the argmax; something like:

```
predicted = net.blobs['prob'].data
```

Comment: yes. you have to take the data from the 'prob', but if you want to see the same pixels as in the image matrix you have to range `cmin` and `cmax`. see my answer here.